# Need to alter "No Paragraph added yet. Select a Paragraph type and press the button below to add one." message - Paragraph Module

Tags: 7, paragraphs

I am using paragraph bundle and I want to alter this message with my custom text "Please click on below button to add data".

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch the contrib module.
Patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2572277#comment-13289889) works for me.